# sharing ListView between classes

Tags: android, eclipse, listview

I have a `ListView` code in a class but I want to show the list into another class. How can I do it?

```
public class listar_teste extends ListActivity 
{
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  String[] names = new String[] { "Linux", "Windows7", "Eclipse", "Suse",
            "Ubuntu", "Solaris", "Android", "iPhone" };
  setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.lista_categorias, names));

  ListView lv = getListView();
  lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
  lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
      // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(),
          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
  });
}
```

}

I want to put in a `ListView` from another class..

Comment: You mean you want to reuse the code in another activity/view?

Comment: You should accept and/or upvote some answers

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to instantiate your specialized version of `ListActivity` wherever you use a normal `ListActivity`. You can even use it in a layout by specifying the full package in the tag name.